# How do I enforce a ManyToMany blank=False constraint on my Django model?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-validation, factory-boy

I'm using Django 3 and Python 3.8.  I have the below model,  Note the "types" ManyToMany field, in which I set "blank" to False.

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType, blank=False)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_phone')
    email = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_email')
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

I want verify a validation error occurs if I leave that field blank, so I have

```
  @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_coop_create_with_no_types(self):
        """ Verify can't create coop if no  """    
        coop = CoopFactory.create(types=[])
        self.assertIsNotNone(coop)
        self.assertNone( coop.id )
```

and use the following factory (with FactoryBoy) to build the model

```
class CoopFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    """
        Define Coop Factory
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Coop

    name = "test model"
    enabled = True
    phone = factory.SubFactory(PhoneContactMethodFactory)
    email = factory.SubFactory(EmailContactMethodFactory)
    web_site = "http://www.hello.com"

    @factory.post_generation
    def addresses(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            # Simple build, do nothing.
            return

        if extracted:
            # A list of types were passed in, use them
            for address in extracted:
                self.addresses.add(address)
        else:
            address = AddressFactory()
            self.addresses.add( address )

    @factory.post_generation
    def types(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            # Simple build, do nothing.
            return

        if extracted:
            # A list of types were passed in, use them
            for _ in range(extracted):
                self.types.add(CoopTypeFactory())
```

However, the "self.assertNone( coop.id )" assertion fails (an ID is generated).  I would expect this not to happen, since I haven't specified any types.  What else do I need to do to enforce my constraint, or should I be using a different constraint?

**Edit:** In response to @Melvyn's suggestion, tried modifying the test to the below

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_coop_create_with_no_types(self):
    """ Test customer model """    # create customer model instance
    coop = CoopFactory.build(types=[])
    coop.full_clean()
    self.assertIsNotNone(coop)
    self.assertIsNone( coop.id )
```

but not only did not get a validation error for the "types," field, got validation errors for the email and phone fields, which are clearly being populated in the factory.

```
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/tests/test_models.py", line 76, in test_coop_create_with_no_types
    coop.full_clean()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1221, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'phone': ['This field cannot be blank.'], 'email': ['This field cannot be blank.']}
```

**Edit:** Per the answer given @ArakkalAbu, I implemented the suggestion (https://github.com/chicommons/maps/blob/master/web/directory/serializers.py) but this test continues to pass

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_coop_create_no_coop_types(self):
    """ Test coop serizlizer model """
    name = "Test 8899"
    street = "222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza, Suite 1212"
    city = "Chicago"
    postal_code = "60654"
    enabled = True
    postal_code = "60654"
    email = "test@example.com"
    phone = "7732441468"
    web_site = "http://www.1871.com"
    state = StateFactory()
    serializer_data = {
        "name": name,
        "types": [
        ],
        "addresses": [{
            "formatted": street,
            "locality": {
                "name": city,
                "postal_code": postal_code,
                "state": state.id
            }
        }],
        "enabled": enabled,
        "phone": {
          "phone": phone
        },
        "email": {
          "email": email
        },
        "web_site": web_site
    }

    serializer = CoopSerializer(data=serializer_data)
    assert serializer.is_valid(True), serializer.errors
```

Comment: To test blank, you would: `coop = CoopFactory.build(types=[]); coop.full_clean()` and that should trigger ValidationError.

Comment: Hi @Melvyn, added the output in response to what you suggested.  Sadly didn't get a validation error on the types field.  Oddly got validation errors on two other fields, which I'm populating in the factory.

Comment: So I just noticed you're using DRF. Then I don't get why you're testing models. DRF overrides model validation - validate your serializers. Also, subfactories and build don't play nicely: build is equivalent of `Model(field=value, field2=value, ...)`, so foreign relations are ignored, as things are not saved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't enforce this constrain, **`blank=False`** into neither ***database-level*** nor ***model-level***. Because every m2m relation has a record with a foreign key to both sides of the m2m relation (the [**`through`**--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) relation).

Also in m2m relations, the m2m items are ***linked*** by a separate operation *under the hood.*

1. Create `CoopFactory` instance
2. Add `CoopType` to `Coop.types` by using [**`.add()`**--(django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) or [**`.set()`**--(django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) methods

That is, you can not create a M2M relation directly by

```
Coop.objects.create(name='foo', types=[1, 2, 3]) # 1,2 & 3 are PKs of `CoopType`
```

This statement trigger an exception by saying,

> TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use **`types.set()`** instead.

---

### What is the best bet?

> as per your [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62916340/how-do-i-enforce-a-manytomany-blank-false-constraint-on-my-django-model#comment111307835_62917007),
>
> I'm not using this in a form though. I'm using the model by a serializer as part of the Django rest framework.

Since you are using DRF, you can validate the ***incoming payload***.

```
class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Coop
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'types': {
                'allow_empty': False
            }
        }
```

```
# execution
s = CoopSerializer(data={'name': 'foo coop', 'types': []})
s.is_valid(True)
s.save()

# excption
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'types': [ErrorDetail(string='This list may not be empty.', code='empty')]}
```

This will help you to ***enforce*** to have a required M2M data.

Comment: To stress that this is the right approach: let's assume we can get blank validation on the model level working in your tests. Then when you send a payload in production with an empty list and your [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#validation-in-rest-framework) field says `allow_empty=True`, your model will be saved even though your test told you it wouldn't.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, thx for this.  Ok I feel I implemented exactly as you said -- https://github.com/chicommons/maps/blob/master/web/directory/serializers.py , but my serializer test continues to show the serializer is valid, even when I pass in empty types (I included a copy of the test in the question, as I had to avoid a few more fields to the JSON to avoid other validation errors).

Comment: @Dave From [django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments), "if the field has already been explicitly declared on the serializer class, then the `extra_kwargs` option will be ignored". On `CoopSerializer`, change `types = CoopTypeSerializer(many=True)` to `types = CoopTypeSerializer(many=True, allow_empty=False)`.

Comment: Yup that was the reason ... wow, I never would have gotten that.

Answer (score 4):

`blank=True` on a `ManyToManyField` is not translated as a DBMS constraint, but will be (for exemple) checked on form validation.

On your unit-test, you use `CoopFactory.create` that seems to not check this logical (and non-dbms) constraint.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#blank

`Note that this is different than null. null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.`

Comment: I'm not using this in a form though.  I'm using the model by a serializer as part of the Django rest framework.